# BeautifulSoup: Parse HTML Table if it contains a keyword

Tags: beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have this html file: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/706688/000119312512154452/d292519ddef14a.htm

And about a thousand more like this, all filed by different firms that use different html formats.

I am interested in one table in that whole document, the beneficial holders table. I want to parse that out using BeautifulSoup.

I am able to parse out all tables in the document, but not the one I need. If I had a list of keywords like "Beneficial","Holders","Ownership" etc, how would I extract only the tables that contain any of the words in the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this and then if statement to match against keywords!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/'
    '706688/000119312512154452/d292519ddef14a.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all('table')
table = tables[3]#find 4th table from the webpage
print(table.text)
```